# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin even when access-control-allow-origin →* is present in response header(checked in postman)

Tags: cors

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://xxxxxxx:8001' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

But access-control-allow-origin →* is present in response header(checked in postman).

> Request and response header in browesr network tab

[image: Request and response header in browesr network tab]

> Browser Console
>   [image]

Comment: You may need to create CORS in the Back End Part, to be able to call your API's.

Comment: also its a website mechanism to tell the browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin so that's why you are receiving your error right now.

Comment: Ya I know I need to add http response header from api level. I am using OSB (Oracle Servcie Bus) for my APIs. I am getting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in postman but not in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for your requests. https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from postman you are not doing an AJAX-request and therefore it is not CORS restricted. Even if you see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response of the postman request the requested resource might need a handler for an OPTIONS request also with the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

The OPTIONS request is done during the preflight for every CORS restricted POST request.

> for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server's data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS